# java command-line args on tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat7, command-line-arguments, jersey-2.0

We have a grizzly-jersey application whose main() takes java command line args(org.kohsuke.args4j) and fed into a class called Features.java
which looked something like below

```
@Option(name = "--enableAuthentication", usage = "--enableAuthentication=true/false")
private static String  enableAuthentication = Boolean.TRUE.toString();
```

we used to deploy the web application as JAR.

Now we moved to WAR model, and we are using tomcat7 as the servlet container.
- how do I pass those cmd line args INTO this application
- how do I access those cmd line args IN the application

**Environment**
jersey 2.9 + spring
tomcat 7.0.46
java8
ubuntu 12.04
maven

Answer (score 0):

in tomcat 7, under bin directory create set `setenv.sh` file

add following line

```
-D--enableAuthentication=true/false
```

This should work.

Comment: This would then apply to all applications running in my tomcat server, right? Is there a way, I can restrict only to one application?

Comment: Yes this will apply to all application.

Comment: (i) I want to restrict/group args of one application and ship it with codebase, not with tomcat installation  (ii) If I am using tomcat installation of eclipse, where do I need to place these ?

Comment: In eclipse, go to run confiugaration -> Agruments -> VM Arguments add '-D--enableAuthentication=true/false'

Comment: This is system property, and will be available to web application that is running under tomcat